# How to use string functions (substring) in the new Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I have text "Welcome to the Automation World". Now i want to extract the word "Automation" from the main string in new Selenium IDE Record and Play using execute script, but not working. Can one help me with example..thanks in advance.

execute Script | return ${var}.substring().. something like this

Comment: Much more context is needed here to get an answer.  Can you upload the HTML of the page you are trying to read?  What do you mean by "extract" the word "Automation"?  Could you share your entire Selenium script?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But as i said im just storing the string into a variable and trying to get substring. Example. Store | Welcome to the Automation world | myVariable and now from that ${myVariable} i need to extract substring "Automation" word and store to another var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to store substring of string variable 'text' into 'subs' variable

```
execute Script | var str = ${text}; return(str.substring(15,25)); | subs
```